# Requests-Html and waiting for the page to fully load

Tags: python, python-requests-html

```
url = 'https://www.funpo.co.il/%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%9F-5'
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)
r.html.render()
ribbons = r.html.find('div.product-ribbon')
print(len(ribbons))
```

This code will randomly return either 0 or 19.
My assumption is that it does not always fully load the page.
However, I'm not sure if it's possible to force it to wait until the page is fully rendered.

Answer (score -1):

I would try to use a timeout in `GET` request. It will require two arguments - the first one is setting session timeout and the second one defines after how many seconds the response will be sent:

```
result = requests.get('http://yoururl.com', timeout=(2, 15))
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help.